# ObjectSpace#allocation_class_path not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Ruby Version 2.1.2

```
class A
  def foo
    ObjectSpace::trace_object_allocations do
      obj = Object.new
      p "#{ObjectSpace::allocation_class_path(obj)}"
    end
  end
end

A.new.foo #=> "Class"
```

The above method is expected to return back the allocation class path of the object.
But I am getting an empty string back instead of "Class".
Is it an implementation bug in the method or the documentation is not updated.

Here is [link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have just found a possible bug in core.
I've already reported the issue to devs, [bug #9938](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9938).

I do suspect `lookup_allocation_info` from object_tracing.c but further investigation required.

**UPDATE:**
Koichi Sasada (aka ko1) already identified the cause and promised to be fixed in forthcomming Ruby 2.2.
In the meantime you may use a workaround to manually cache object names in a module with

`ObjectSpace.each_object(Module){|o| o.name}`

placed before objects tracing code.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try like this,

```
require 'objspace'
class A
  def foo
    ObjectSpace::trace_object_allocations do
      obj = Object.new
      p "#{ObjectSpace::allocation_class_path(obj)}"
    end
  end
end
```

A.new.foo

#"Class"
   => "Class"

Comment: Did it work for you. If yes, on which ruby version. This code does not seem to work for me. And it is exactly same as the code I have mentioned in question. ;-)

Comment: @Sanket For me also it gives empty string `""`.. I don't know how you got `"Class"`

Comment: Version: ruby 2.1.2p95

Comment: By the way I tried it even on ruby-2.1.1 it does not seem to work and returns empty string.

Comment: So wherever you test it won't work. Not in code nor in console

Comment: I have test it in rails console once again and its worked. :), but not worked in irb :(

Comment: @Sanket I can confirm this behavior. Still investigating why is there a difference.